# How to Toggle Classname in ReactJS when button is Clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to change the hamburger style of menu when I click the button. The toggle for opening the menu is already okay but I'm having a problem when changing the `className` of my hamburger menu.

**This is my constructor and function**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { menuOpen: true }
    this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
}

toggleMenu = () => {
    const {show} = this.state;
    this.setState({show : !show});
}
```

I am binding my toggleMenu function in this section here:

```
<div className={this.toggleMenu ? "hamburger hamburger--emphatic-r" : "hamburger hamburger--emphatic-r is-Active"} onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
<div className="hamburger-box">
<div className="hamburger-inner"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I created a class Component called NavMenu and pass that function when user will click the hamburger menu.

```
class NavMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav className="isMobile">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#bottom2">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Clients</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
             </nav>
        )
    }
}
```

And here is my whole class component to fully understand the process. 
**Class Component Source Code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class nav extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props)

this.state = { menuOpen: true }
this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
}

toggleMenu = () => {
const {show} = this.state;
this.setState({show : !show});
}

render() {
console.log(this.toggleMenu);
return (
<div id="nav_area">
<div className="nav_toggle_button">
<div className={this.toggleMenu ? "hamburger hamburger--emphatic-r" : "hamburger hamburger--emphatic-r is-Active"} onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
<div className="hamburger-box">
    <div className="hamburger-inner"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>                    
<nav className="isWeb">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bottom2">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
{this.state.show && <NavMenu/>}
</div>
)
}
}

class NavMenu extends Component {
render() {
return (
<nav className="isMobile">
<ul>
<li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#bottom2">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Clients</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
)
}
}

export default nav
```

What seems to be lacking in this end in order to change the className when clicked? What I'm trying to solve is when the hamburger menu is Clicked it will show the navigation items and also changed the hambuger from `hamburger hamburger--emphatic-r` to `hamburger hamburger--emphatic-r is-Active`.

Comment: Looks like you should put this.state.menuopen instead of this.toggleMenu in your className check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ternary condition should be `this.state.show`:

```
<div className={this.toggleMenu ? "hamburger hamburger--emphatic-r" : "hamburger hamburger--emphatic-r is-Active"} onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
```

should be

```
<div className={this.state.show ? "hamburger hamburger--emphatic-r" : "hamburger hamburger--emphatic-r is-Active"} onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
```

And also in the constructor you're using the wrong name. It should be:

```
this.state = { show: true }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have not declraed `show` object in state , no need `menuOpen` just replace it with `show` and in ternary use that show state**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class nav extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props)

this.state = { show: true }
this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
}

toggleMenu = () => {
const {show} = this.state;
this.setState({show : !show});
}

render() {
console.log(this.toggleMenu);
return (
<div id="nav_area">
<div className="nav_toggle_button">
<div className={this.state.show ? "hamburger hamburger--emphatic-r" : "hamburger hamburger--emphatic-r is-Active"} onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
<div className="hamburger-box">
    <div className="hamburger-inner"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>                    
<nav className="isWeb">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bottom2">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
{this.state.show && <NavMenu/>}
</div>
)
}
}

class NavMenu extends Component {
render() {
return (
<nav className="isMobile">
<ul>
<li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#bottom2">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Clients</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
)
}
}

export default nav
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If you declare a `menuOpen` in the constructor, you should use `menuOpen` state in `toggleMenu` function instead of `show` state (show state has not declared yet).
2. You should use `this.state.menuOpen` instead of function `this.toggleMenu` for conditional operator.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class nav extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props)

this.state = { menuOpen: true }
this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
}

toggleMenu = () => {
const {menuOpen} = this.state;
this.setState({menuOpen : !menuOpen});
}

render() {
console.log(this.state.menuOpen);
return (
<div id="nav_area">
<div className="nav_toggle_button">
<div className={this.state.menuOpen ? "hamburger hamburger--emphatic-r" : "hamburger hamburger--emphatic-r is-Active"} onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
<div className="hamburger-box">
    <div className="hamburger-inner"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>                    
<nav className="isWeb">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bottom2">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
{this.state.show && <NavMenu/>}
</div>
)
}
}

class NavMenu extends Component {
render() {
return (
<nav className="isMobile">
<ul>
<li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#bottom2">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Clients</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Login</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
)
}
}

export default nav
```